# Using QGraphicsScene ItemAt() to detect QGraphicsLineItem

Tags: qt

I have a QGraphicsScene which stores QGraphicsLinesItems and QGraphicsRectItems.

I am using the QGraphicsScene method to itemsAt() and I pass through x and y co ordiantes to return the QGraphicsItem and I use the following:

```
        QPointF getItemPos= this->mapToScene(this->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()));
        QGraphicsItem *itm  = scene->itemAt(getItemPos.x(),getItemPos.y());
        QGraphicsLineItem *lineItm;
        QGraphicsRectItem *rectItm;
        if((lineItm = dynamic_cast<QGraphicsLineItem*>(itm))){
            // do stuff with as_pnedge
            qDebug("Line");
        }else if((rectItm = dynamic_cast<QGraphicsRectItem*>(itm))){
            // do stuff with as_pnitem
            qDebug("Rect");
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug("Select Item");
        }
```

The issue I am having is that QGraphicsRectItem is returned fine and can be detected. But no matter where I click around the QGraphicsLineItems it can never detect and return the item. Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your line uses a cosmetic pen (width of zero), it means that the `shape()` method will return a zero width `QPainterPath` ([source code](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/raw/11ff42af39f1b81e8e35451bf7128cbafd294da7/src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp), search for "qt_graphicsItem_shapeFromPath").

You will have to derive from `QGraphicsLineItem` and reimplement `shape()` to clamp the minimum pen width for `QPainterPathStroker` to something reasonable.